# Angular 2 app loading slow in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, firefox

I've used Chrome for development and app always has loaded fast there. But now I tried to run in on firefox and it takes about 8 seconds to load with horrible pauses and even a preloader at place of favicon stops for some moments during loading process. I've recorded the loading process with performance mozila tool and got multiple calls of `globalZoneAwareCallback`, `GC` calls and multiple of style recalculations. I got almost the same picture in my chrome browser except for style to not recompile that much, but why it's so faster here than in firefox? Is it because of styles? How can I fix performance of loading in mozila?

Comment: Try to `enableProdMode()` and close Firefox's dev tools?

Comment: The same effect( I'm running it by `npm start`.

Comment: Well, you are right about loading it faster when running prod build, but still it's a bit strange that it's so slow and stopping in dev version only in mozila.

Comment: In my case, I've speed up by disabling some plugins. But I still notice a big lag in angular made apps on firefox.

Comment: Specially these two: LastPass && "Dark Background and light text"